# New questions on live home page display improperly

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackapps, live

I was browsing Stack Apps earlier today and a little box popped up indicating that there were new questions. It looked something like this:

[image: new activity]

After clicking the provided link, here is what was displayed:

[image]

The new question that was added to the list was not styled the same way as the other questions on the page - the icon was not displayed, the description was missing, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updates for the homepage of StackApps is custom.  Realtime updates have been disabled for the apps tab.